# Google App Engine Deploy error 13 - Deployment Manager operation failed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to deploy an app first time and getting this at the very end of 'gcloud app deploy' operation.

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Deployment Manager operation failed, name: operation-1522364367335-5689513556e59-0732922b-1662dc1e, error:

```
[  
   {  
      "code":"RESOURCE_ERROR",
      "location":"/deployments/aef-default-20180329t155754/resources/aef-default-20180329t155754-hcfw",
      "message":{  
         "ResourceType":"compute.v1.firewall",
         "ResourceErrorCode":"404",
         "ResourceErrorMessage":{  
            "code":404,
            "errors":[  
               {  
                  "domain":"global",
                  "message":"The resource 'projects/kubernetes-staging/global/networks/default' was not found",
                  "reason":"notFound"
               }
            ],
            "message":"The resource 'projects/kubernetes-staging/global/networks/default' was not found",
            "statusMessage":"Not Found",
            "requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/kubernetes-staging/global/firewalls",
            "httpMethod":"POST"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "code":"RESOURCE_ERROR",
      "location":"/deployments/aef-default-20180329t155754/resources/aef-default-20180329t155754-00it",
      "message":{  
         "ResourceType":"compute.v1.instanceTemplate",
         "ResourceErrorCode":"404",
         "ResourceErrorMessage":{  
            "code":404,
            "errors":[  
               {  
                  "domain":"global",
                  "message":"The resource 'projects/kubernetes-staging/global/networks/default' was not found",
                  "reason":"notFound"
               }
            ],
            "message":"The resource 'projects/kubernetes-staging/global/networks/default' was not found",
            "statusMessage":"Not Found",
            "requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/kubernetes-staging/global/instanceTemplates",
            "httpMethod":"POST"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, the default global network (entitled 'default') hasn't been found, which appears to be the reason why your app isn't deploying.

You can create a global [**network**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) by executing this command in **Cloud Shell** before deploying your app:

```
$ gcloud compute networks create default --subnet-mode auto
```

If you didn't modify the original default network, it would suggest that the issue is related to the network settings in your **app.yaml** configuration file. Information on configuring these settings can be found [**here**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings).

If you follow the steps above but are still having trouble, I suggest that you create a new issue in the [**Public Issue Tracker**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) and provide us with the contents of your **app.yaml** file as well as your Project ID, where I'd be happy to investigate further.

(Disclaimer: I work for Google Cloud Platform Support)